# How to properly flush disk cache using ioctl (raw partition) in linux

Tags: c, linux, flush, ioctl

I am trying to use ioctl to make sure changes written directly to the volume are hitting the disk. 
fsync() obviously not available in raw partition.  sync() is horrible solution too (in order to flush 64MB, i need entire life time to wait in sync)

so.. here is what i am trying to do - getting errno 25.

/dev/sda3 is a *raw* unmounted partition on ssd drive

```
open(_fd, "/dev/sda3", ...)
pwritev(_fd, ...)

ioctl(_fd, BLKFLSBUF, 0)   <== errno = 25.
```

Ubuntu 14.04, c

Note:

```
hdparm -W 0 /dev/sda3
```

fails on : Inappropriate ioctl for device.

how can I find the suitable flushing method for my ssd ?

Comment: Is using direct I/O or /dev/raw an option?

Comment: What do you mean, *"fsync() obviously not available in raw partition"*? `fsync(_fd)` and `fdatasync(_fd)` should flush the contents to the underlying device even if `_fd` refers to a block device. The actual flushing is done by [fs/block_dev.c:blkdev_fsync()](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/block_dev.c#n368) (via [fs/sync.c:fdatasync()](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/sync.c#n230) → do_fsync() → vfs_fsync() → vfs_fsync_range(), then blkdev_fsync() via file_operations structure).

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - I'm opening /dev/sda3.  not /dev/raw.   I took another machine where hdparam -W 0 worked. Still ioctl fails with errno=25. So my question is - can I use ioctl BLKFLSHBUF on /dev/sdxN ?

Comment: @NominalAnimal - fsync gives me rates of memory. not disk.  it seems it does nothing.   My scenario: 1) create unmounted partition  2) fd = open("/dev/sdaxN", ..permissions..) 3) writes  .. now fsync does nothing and ioctl(fd, BLKFLSBUF) fails.    What am I missing ?  I want to make sure data is written physically

Answer (score 3):

I cannot duplicate `ioctl(fd, BLKFLSBUF)` errors in Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS on x86_64 using 4.2.0-42-generic kernel.

I tested both full block devices, and individual partitions on them. Could you try the following minimal test program?

Save the following as e.g. **block-flush.c**:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int arg, descriptor, result;

    if (argc < 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s BLOCK-DEVICE-OR-PARTITION ...\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {

        do {
            descriptor = open(argv[arg], O_RDWR);
        } while (descriptor == -1 && errno == EINTR);
        if (descriptor == -1) {
            const int cause = errno;
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot open device: %s [%d].\n", argv[arg], strerror(cause), cause);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        errno = 0;
        result = ioctl(descriptor, BLKFLSBUF);
        if (result && errno) {
            const int cause = errno;
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot flush device: %s [%d].\n", argv[arg], strerror(cause), cause);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        } else
        if (result)
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Flush returned %d.\n", argv[arg], result);
        else
        if (errno) {
            const int cause = errno;
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Flush returned zero, but with error: %s [%d]. Ignored.\n", argv[arg], strerror(cause), cause);
        }

        result = close(descriptor);
        if (result == -1) {
            const int cause = errno;
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Error closing device: %s [%d].\n", argv[arg], strerror(cause), cause);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Flushed.\n", argv[arg]);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile it using

```
gcc -Wall -O2 block-flush.c -o block-flush
```

and run it (as root), specifying the partition(s) or block device(s) at the command line:

```
sudo ./block-flush /dev/sda3
```

For me, this outputs `/dev/sdxN: Flushed.` for unmounted partitions, as well as the disks (`/dev/sdx`) themselves. (Also, adding `fdatasync(descriptor)` before the ioctl() does not change anything, and it too succeeds without any errors.)

Also, I happened to test this using an external USB SATA docking station and a "loud" 3.5" drive (such docks needing external power; USB power not being sufficient for these larger drives with spinning platters). I could easily hear that the ioctl() does access the physical device, so it is not a no-op (and, again, the minimal test program never reported any failures in my tests). After closing the descriptor, the disk is also quiescent until the disk or partitions are opened for further accesses. Of course, these observations are only valid for USB-connected hard drives, and only on this particular kernel and hardware architecture, but in my opinion, it does indicate that the `ioctl(descriptor, BLKFLSBUF);` should work for unmounted partitions and full block devices, in the expected manner.